# How to incorporate ES6 transpiler into Angular gulp build process

Tags: angularjs, gulp

In order to prepare my app for production I use the below gulp task. The task is quiet self explanatory, all `.js` files are uglified and placed into build folder

```
var jsLibFilter = $.filter('**/lib.js');
var jsAppFilter = $.filter('**/app.js');
var buildPath = './build/';

gulp.task('build', function() {

  return gulp.src(config.index)

   <!-- pick up all files in index which are under "lib.js" tag -->
    .pipe(jsLibFilter)
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsLibFilter.restore())

   <!-- pick up all files in index which are under "app.js" tag -->
     .pipe(jsAppFilter)
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsAppFilter.restore())

   .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath));

});
```

There is a whole bunch of other things that happen within the upper task which I have not included for sake of clarity.

A small snapshot of index.html below:

```
<body>
<!-- build:js js/lib.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->

<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

 ...other libraries here

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->

<script src="/client/app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="/client/app/history/historyController.js"></script>

..other source code files here

<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
```

I have two specific questions:

1. How to incorporate ES6 during development. e.g. how do I apply babel transpiler while developing.
   Do keep in mind that during development I am serving files from the "/app" folder
2. How to incorporate ES6 during production 
   During production the files are served from build folder for which I have provided the build task above.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel

Comment: I am aware of gulp-babel.. how to incorporate that during development process ?